# error occurred during the build initializing java tooling eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, svn, glassfish

I saw that this problem has other "ASK" here but my situation is a little different. I work with a SVN and after a commit that someone gave two days ago i can´t work anymore. Everytime that i download the project from SVN it´s ok , but when i close eclipse, i close glassfish and i start them again i get this error:

error occurred during the build initializing java tooling eclipse

this append just at the beginning, when eclipse has just been started. 
I saw that the version that gives the error changed the .classpath and the oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.syslib.xml, while all other classe are normal classes that in my opinion cannot create all this problems.
furthermore if i close the error message dialog whit the "java initzialazing error" i start to recive many other kind of errors, and if i try to deploy my project into glassfish it says that the listener cannot find the class in my project.
So in my opinion my error is related with the .classpath or/and with oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.syslib.xml.

I´ll appreciate anykind of help of suggestion that could help me

Comment: Take a look at the eclipse log file to see if anything stood out. It's usually located in your workspace as `.metadata/.log.`.

Comment: i guess this error have sense       java.lang.NullPointerException
 at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.internal.SystemLibrariesSetting.getSourcePath(SystemLibrariesSetting.java:85)
 at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.GlassFishInstall.classpath(GlassFishInstall.java:421)
 at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.internal.SystemLibrariesContainer.<init>(SystemLibrariesContainer.java:75)